# How do I send multiple results from one command to another in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I'm not sure if this is possible in one line (i.e., without writing a script), but I want to run an `ls | grep` command and then for each result, pipe it to another command.

To be specific, I've got a directory full of images and I only want to view certain ones. I can filter the images I'm interested in with `ls | grep -i <something>`, which will return a list of matching files. Then for each file, I want to view it by passing it in to `eog`.

I've tried simply passing the results in to `eog` like so:

`eog $(ls | grep -i <something>)`

This doesn't quite work as it will only open the first entry in the result list.

So, how can I execute `eog FILENAME` for each entry in the result list without having to bundle this operation into a script?

**Edit:** As suggested in the answers, I can use a `for` loop like so:

`for i in 'ls | grep -i ...'; do eog $i; done`

This works, but the loop waits to iterate until I close the currently opened `eog` instance.

Ideally I'd like for `n` instances of `eog` to open all at once, where `n` is the number of results returned from my `ls | grep` command. Is this possible?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: The above command works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping over the results:

```
for i in `ls | grep -i <something>`; do
    eog $i
done
```

Or you can one-line it:

```
for i in `ls | grep -i <something>`; do eog $i; done
```

**Edit:** If you want the `eog` instances to open in parallel, launch each in a new process with `eog $i &`.  The updated one-liner would then read:

```
for i in `ls | grep -i <something>`; do (eog $i &); done
```

Comment: Caveat: spaces in filenames might throw this off a bit.  If that is the case, try using `find` instead of `ls`+`grep` and pipe the results to `xargs`.

Comment: if  that's the case, use shell expansion.

Comment: Always use shell expansion, never use `ls`.

Comment: @bta: I tried `do eog $i &; done` but I get a syntax error (unexpected token ';'). I then tried `do 'eog $i &'; done` but that doesn't open them in parallel. Any way to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: @bta: The subshell isn't needed, `for i in ...; do eog "$i" & done` works as well.

Answer (score 8):

I would use `xargs`:

```
$ ls | grep -i <something> | xargs -n 1 eog
```

Comment: This will grep for the something in each of the files found, not grep the file *names* for the something.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want to recurse, and then it's roughly equivalent to `eog *something*`.

Comment: That's much worse than your previous solution, breaking on every "special" character etc. If you don't want to recurse, use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`.

Comment: @Philipp, if the OP thinks `ls | grep` is ok, I think it's ok.

Comment: unless you have special pattern you want to grep where normal shell expansion cannot provide, using ls with grep is useless. Use shell expansion.

Answer (score 3):

A bare `ls` piped into grep is sort of redundant given `arbitrary?sh*ll-glo[bB]` patterns (unless there are too many matches to fit on a command line in which case the `find | xargs` combinations in other answers should be used.

`eog` is happy to take multiple file names so

```
eog pr0n*really-dirty.series?????.jpg
```

is fine and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '...' -exec eog '{}' ';'
```

or

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex '...' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 eog
```

If the pattern is not too complex, then globbing is possible, making the call much easier:

```
for file in *.png
do
  eog -- "$file"
done
```

Bash also has builtin regex support:

```
pattern='.+\.png'
for file in *
do
  [[ $file =~ $pattern ]] && eog -- "$file"
done
```

Never use `ls` in scripts, and never use `grep` to filter file names.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for image in *pattern*
do
  eog "$image"
done
```

Bash 4

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s globstar
for image in **/*pattern*
do
    eog "$image"
done
```

Comment: The OP specifically requested a non-script solution.

Comment: You can enter these lines in interactive mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over the number of arguments passed on to eog, you may use "xargs -L" in combination with "bash -c":

```
printf "%s\n" {1..10} | xargs -L 5 bash -c 'echo "$@"' arg0

ls | grep -i <something> | xargs -L 5 bash -c 'eog "$@"' arg0
```